# Test for app closing with Calabash

Tags: ios, bdd, calabash

Our iOS app opens links in Safari.  Is it possible to use a Calabash test to check that our app goes into the background when particular links are clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Once the link is touched and Safari becomes the frontmost app, the cucumber processes loses connection with the calabash server and there is no way for calabash to interact with your app.